# Tableau KPI prev value depending on variable

Tags: tableau-api

am trying to get Previous Sum(of someField) based on a variable value which is an Id.

This is not a table, Im doing a KPI

On Qlik you would do something like:

```
SUM({<Id={"$(=Max(vVariable),-1))"}>} someField)
```

But I can not achieve it on Tableau, off course is due to my lack of knowledge, unfortunatelly time is tinking at work and wanted to see if anyone has any input!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you may use a sample input like the Superstore (using sales as metric), this could be what you're looking for:

[image]

In red you can see your "variable" which allows you to select a value and in blue you'll find the unique row for the previous value (Order ID sorted).

The first thing you need to to do is creating a parameter based on all the Order ID values:

[image]

Then things start to get a bit complicated if you're not familiar with LOD (Level of details) and the order of execution in Tableau, especially for filters.

Assuming that you can get some information on your own (otherwise, feel free to ask), the first thing you nee to to do is to "pre-calculate" the equivalent of a table having a rowe for each Order ID, in which you also have the previous Order ID value.

You can achive this combining Fixed (LOD) and Lookup function, creating this Calculated Field "Lookup Order ID":

```
LOOKUP( max({ FIXED [Order ID] : MAX([Order ID])}),1)
```

This is actually just a calculated field that you want to "fix" because you need the filter to act after you have made that previous calculus, and then you shift your data by 1 row backward.

Once you've done that, you just nee to create another calculated field in order to test your parametric value, and it could be something like this "check param":

```
[Lookup Order ID] = [Order ID param]
```

Moving this calculated field in the filter section and selecting just "true" values, you'll get that unique rows like in the initial image, showing the previous value (blue) related to the one you select in the parameter drop-down menu (red).

Comment: Many thanks for the input, really appreciate it !

Comment: my pleasure... quite interesting topic ;-)